# .NET Business Object Collection (List)

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance

I'm wanting to create a business object collection class (List of T). My business objects have a Deleted property (so I can keep track for DB deletes later). The collection class needs to override the remove, for-each enumeration methods etc. of List so that I can mark the business objects as deleted instead of being 'physically' removed from the list, and skip over them during an enumeration. So far I have a class that inherits List(of BusObject), but i've found some List methods (ie Remove) are not overridable. Am I approaching this wrong? Maybe I shouldn't be inheriting List and manage a list internally with my own methods?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own `ICollection` as such:

The internal collection, including deleted items, can be accessed using the `InternalCollection` property if you would like to write to a database, etc.

Opted to throw `NotSupportedException` for the `CopyTo` method since it wouldn't be obvious what to implement there (do we want to copy over the deleted items as well?).

```
class SoftDeleteCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
    where T : class, ISoftDelete
{
    public ICollection<T> InternalCollection { get; private set; }

    public SoftDeleteCollection()
    {
        this.InternalCollection = new List<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.InternalCollection.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.InternalCollection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (T item in this.InternalCollection.Where(item => !item.IsDeleted))
        {
            item.IsDeleted = false;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.InternalCollection.Any(i => i == item && !i.IsDeleted);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (this.Contains(item))
        {
            item.IsDeleted = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.InternalCollection.Count(item => !item.IsDeleted); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from the `Collection<T>` class and override the appropriate methods like   `RemoveItem` and `ClearItems`.
Take a look at the `GetEnumerator`

More information on this can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132415(v=vs.110).aspx)

When I think about this, I think another approach could be easier, especially when it comes to iterating over the collection and skipping the soft-deleted items:
Create your own collection class by inhering from `Collection<T>`.  When deleting an item, you should not only set the `IsDeleted` flag, but remove the item from the collection, and add it to an additional collection that is defined in your collection class.

Like this:

```
public class MyBusinessCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : BusObject
{
    private readonly List<T> _deletedItems = new List<T>();

    protected override RemoveItem( int index )
    {
       var item = this[index];

       item.Deleted = true;

       _deletedItems.Add(item);

       base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetDeletedItems()
    {
         return _deletedItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at inheriting from ObservableCollection. That might help you.

Class ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Sorta similar thread, with a helpful comment in it: [C# Custom Observable Collection - Should I use Composition or Inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665994/c-sharp-custom-observable-collection-should-i-use-composition-or-inheritance)